# Compering an acoustic modeling RIR method with the best realistic method

Tags: waves, acoustics, simulations

I have implemented a method for simulating a point source located outside of a shew-box room in vacant space and I wish to compare the resulted impulse response (IR) with a more accurate one. Is there a free simulation program in which I can easily build such a scenario and calculate the IR with a very long, very accurate mathematical model?

My goal is to validate the results of my algorithm by comparing it with a method based on a wave equation solver. Hence, I wish it to be:

- Able to generate an IR from point a to b after solving the wave eq. - must.
- Free to use - must.
- Easy to learn or with good tutorials - preferable.

What is the best solution in my case?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more info regarding your simulation and what exactly you consider to be a "very long, very accurate mathematical model". There are numerous modelling techniques out there, ranging from analytical solutions of the wave equation (of various complexities) to numerical computation methods such as Finite Differences, Finite Differences Time Domain, Finite Elements and Boundary Elements.

Comment: @ZaellixA I have edited and added a line about my goal. The accuracy should be with respect to that goal.

Comment: I believe you should be a bit more explanatory on the technique you used in order for people to be able to provide information on a "more accurate" method. Other than that, you could possibly use a ray-tracing software (such as ODEON or CATT-Acoustics) to model your space with a point source placed at the appropriate position. Additionally, you could use a numerical modelling software such as COMSOL to solve the wave-equation.  Finally, a free package for Octave (https://wiki.octave.org/Fem-fenics) can be used.